# Why Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode value="Get"?

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to understand what you can achieve by setting Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode value = "Get". If the value is set to "Get" , which means anonymous user will only able to get data using HTTP Get. What if i have a web page which allows unregistered users to submit feedback on my website ? Does "Get" value restrict them to do that ? Should i change the value to "All" instead ???

The reason i asked is because I am unable to save a sample document when the value is "Get". My web application throws a "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." error. In order to solve this error, i need to set the "Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode" to "All". Is it safe to set the value to "All" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found my answer. It is ok for me to set Raven/AnonymousUserAccessMode to "All". My database is inaccessible to the outside world because my port 8080 is firewalled.